# Parsing through MSDN text?

Tags: c#, json, html-agility-pack

Trying to figure out how I can parse through this information, it looks like JSON but I can't tell if it is or not (no .json at the end). I've been treating it as JSON and have been trying to parse through it

```
        string url = "https://services.social.microsoft.com/searchapi/en-US/Msdn?query=" + query + "&amp;maxnumberedpages=5&amp;encoderesults=1&amp;highlightqueryterms=1";

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();

        List<string[]> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(objText);

        foreach (string[] test in data)
        {
            foreach (string sub_text in test)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sub_text);
            }

        }
```

But it gives me an error that it's not a JSON array, so I'm beginning to think it's not JSON.

I'm just looking for a push in the right direction, here's a sample of the data I would get:

https://services.social.microsoft.com/searchapi/en-US/Msdn?query=dynamic%20arrays&maxnumberedpages=5&encoderesults=1&highlightqueryterms=1

and I would want to grab the all arrays that the have 'id' at the start. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid Json.

Problem is that you are trying to Deserialize into Array which is not correct.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(objText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is this line

```
List<string[]> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string[]>>(objText);
```

What you are trying to deserialize is not a string array, it's an object.  To correctly deserialize it, you would need to create a set of classes that model the data structure.  You may also explore using a Jobject in the [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library as an alternative.